# Jw player: want to play mp3 audio in jw html5 player with prev/next navigation

Tags: jquery, html, jwplayer

I am using this below code. MP3 audio playing successfully .

But why not prev next control coming ?

and why the primary: "html5" not working. i want to play it in JW Html5 player not in flash player.
why the flash player is coming?

Thank you for your support.

updated fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_kumar/MFs9h/

Thank you for your support.

```
<div id='jwplayer-1'>jwplayer-1</div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        if (typeof (jQuery) == "function") {
                            (function ($) {
                                $.fn.fitVids = function () {}
                            })(jQuery)
                        };

                    jwplayer('jwplayer-1').setup({
                      "height": 106,
                     "width": 480,
                     "stretching": "fill",
                     "primary": "html5",
                     "listbar": {
                       "position": 'bottom',
                       "size": 80
                     },
                      "playlist": [{ 
                       image: "vtts/wizard.gif", file: "http://128f1.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Dhoom%203%20(2013)/01%20-%20Malang%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", title: "Dhoom 3-1"
                       },{
                       image: "vtts/wizard.gif", file: "http://128f1.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Dhoom%203%20(2013)/02%20-%20Kamli%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", title: "Dhoom 3-2"
                       },{
                       image: "vtts/wizard.gif", file: "http://128f1.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Dhoom%203%20(2013)/03%20-%20Tu%20Hi%20Junoon%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", title: "Dhoom 3-3"
                       },{
                       image: "vtts/wizard.gif", file: "http://128f1.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Dhoom%203%20(2013)/08%20-%20Dhoom%20Machale%20Dhoom%20(Arabic)%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", title: "Dhoom 3-4"
                     }]
                     });
                </script>
```

Comment: In the JW Player, the previous and next buttons only show when the playlist is not visible. I would remove the listbar from your code.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer : Is there no way to show both prev/next button and listbar together

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer ok thankyou.. this could be a drawback for your JW player. I need to try another option.

Comment: i will customize your jw player according to my requirement..

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer why the primary: "html5" not working. i want to play in Html5 player not in flash player.

Comment: Where are you trying this?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer please. http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_kumar/MFs9h/

Comment: You only get the prev/next buttons when there is no listbar. This works fine in HTML5 mode for me - http://jsfiddle.net/8ADVQ/

Answer (score 1):

As Ethan has mentioned, the previous and next buttons only show when the playlist is not visible. you should remove he list bar from your code.

**[SETTING MULTIPLE ITEMS](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28842/working-with-playlists)**

This setup contains two playlist items, each with a title, image and single media source. This source is loaded through the file shortcut:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    playlist: [{
        image: "/assets/sintel.jpg",
        file: "/assets/sintel.mp4",
        title: "Sintel Movie Trailer"
    },{
        image: "/assets/bunny.jpg",
        file: "/assets/bunny.mp4",
        title: "Big Buck Bunny Movie Trailer"
    }] });
```

**

> **JW Player will play these videos sequentially, displaying prev/next
>   buttons in the controlbar to quickly jump from one item to the other.
>   Alternatively, the listbar can be shown next to the video display for
>   easy playlist browsing.**

**

> **Check out this jsfiddle link**

[Jwplayer With ListBar](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/pN96N/7/)

[Jwplayer without ListBar](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/pN96N/8/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for help but hitesh where is your improve code. above these two fiddle shows same result as a have tried already. 
As you mentioned that your custom improved code will show both navigation and playlist together but i am sorry there is no result seems for my problem's solution.